# Declension of appositions

Tags: grammatical-case, definite-article, apposition

The Wikipedia article for *Tora* in German goes like [this](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tanach):

> Die Tora [...] ist der erste Teil des Tanach, **der** hebräischen Bibel.

It seemed to me that the highlighted article is part of an explanatory phrase, an apposition:

> The Torah is the first part of Tanach, **the**  Hebrew Bible.
>
> *not:* The Torah is the first part of Tanach, **of the**  Hebrew Bible.

And as such, should be in nominative, not again in genitive. Why is it? Is it wrong to use nominative again?

Comment: I'm not a grammar expert,just a native speaker, and your sentence sounds fine to me. [The canoo.net article on apposition](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html) (in German) states "Das Nomen der Apposition und das Nomen, das durch die Apposition näher bestimmt wird, stehen meistens im gleichen Kasus."

Comment: It just sounded so counterintuitive to me... it's not wrong, but "alternative" in my native language (Portuguese). One shouldn't presume anything, anyway. :-)

Comment: @Fred Indeed, for Romance languages it doesn't make sense. But it's a nice feature once you get used to it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Jein*. Indeed one of your assumptions is right: it's an apposition. Second, appositions inherit the grammatical case, in this example genitive, of the noun they describe.

Hence, your sentence is correct. 
However, according [to this article](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition), it *might*  in absence of an article for *hebräische Bibel*, stand in nominative (the writing style is questionable, though).

> Die Tora [...] ist der erste Teil des Tanach, hebräische Bibel.
>   <sup>(theoretically possible, stylistically bad)</sup>

Another example:

> Er kennt ziemlich genau die Geschichte Schuberts, *des großen Komponisten*.
>   Hans gibt Jonas, *dem Sohn Petras*, einen Apfel.

Comment: Might I add that *[…] des Tanach, hebräische Bibel* sounds so incredibly wrong to me that I would correct it, if I heard it. I'm not sure I would allow an apposition without an article *anywhere*. Maybe unless the describing word is a name (*der hebräischen Bibel, Tanach*) but probably even then. I get the same feeling with Wikipedia's 'official' example, which just sounds wrong if it's lacking an article.

Comment: "the writing style is questionable" - indeed. If you put "hebräische Bibel" in parentheses, this can work ("Die Tora [...] ist der erste Teil des Tanach (hebräische Bibel)."); it's not a very elaborate, but a short and still acceptable way of writing. With a comma, however, it just seems either wrong, or like a *very* informal style of writing that directly replicates the way spoken language (i.e. possibly without forming complete sentences).

Comment: Unfortunately, what one can observe (especially from TV journalist texts) seems to indicate a "rule" that any apposition that does not immediately follow a short subject at the beginning of the sentence "should" use Dativ (which would produce "Er kennt ziemlich genau die Geschichte Schuberts, dem großen Komponisten" - shudder)